# Latex: access the content of an environment while using \newenvironment

Tags: latex

I'm trying to make my own environment with \newenvironment.

Is it somehow possible to access the "body" of the environment?

For example if the user uses

```
\begin{myenv}
    i'm the content
\end{myenv}
```

i want to analyze the "i'm the content" in the definition of the environment.

Thanks in advance,

Jan Oliver Oelerich

Comment: How do you intend to "analyze" it?

Comment: wanna count the & in the input to automatically create a \begin{tabular}{cccc...c} with the correct number of c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use package 'environ'.

```
\NewEnviron{myenv}{\colorbox[gray]{0.7}{\BODY}}
```

where `\BODY` is a your "body".